# Не получается отправить get запрос

Tags: c#, httpclient

Я устанавливаю все заголовки, и пытаюсь поймать куки, куки нету, заголовки установлены, сервер выдает все равно 404

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer }; ;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "https://www.icstrvl.ru/srch_v4/index.html");

            var html = await client.GetAsync("https://www.icstrvl.ru/srch_v4/index.html")
            Console.WriteLine(html);
// Получаю куки \/
            IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies13 = cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(link)).Cast<Cookie>();
            foreach (Cookie cookiew1 in responseCookies13)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cookiew1.Name + ": " + cookiew1.Value);
                cookieContainer.Add(cookiew1);
            }
// Устанавливаю заголовки \/
            var server = html.Headers.GetValues("Server").FirstOrDefault();
            var ETag = html.Headers.GetValues("ETag").FirstOrDefault();
            var Date = html.Headers.GetValues("Date").FirstOrDefault();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Server", server);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ETag", ETag);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Date", Date);

            string link2 = "https://www.icstrvl.ru/srch_v4/json/sdata.json?city=538625&cnt=14472441&spo=0&ct%5B%5D=5&tt%5B%5D=65977793&transport=all_transports&ad=2&ch=0&infant=0&ml%5B%5D=1771&d%5B%5D=7&date=2020-07-31&date1=2020-07-31&cur=0&mp=&nonstop=1&gf=1&pg=1&ver=1455&__mthd=getSearchResult&lttt=1";
            var html2 = await client.GetAsync(link2);
            Console.WriteLine(html2);
```

Если запустите код, увидите, какие заголовки и куки устанавливаются, после выдает 404, пол дня пытаюсь понять чего не хватает

Comment: Вам не нужны заголовки, вам нужна только верная ссылка и 2 cookie `__ydma` и `tracking`. Я вижу у вас `cookieContainer.Add(cookiew1);`, ок, 2 вопроса: 1. Вы уверены, что там есть эти 2 cookie? 2. Вы уверены, что cookie содержат верный хост?

Comment: Да, я был озадачен, что вставляю все 3 ссылки которые я вижу и думаю что они подойдут, и там нету ни одной куки, скорее всего как вы сказали, мне нужно найти нужную ссылку, но может быть это смешно звучит, но я не могу найти нужную ссылку, может быть такое, что эти 2 значения спрятаны в html и я должен их найти?

Comment: Куки как мне отображает, содержат нужный хост `www.icstrvl.ru`

Comment: `tracking` вам отдает сайт при первом его посещение, а `__ydma` всегда статична, скорей это просто некий идентификатор, у меня он `afx2232_32324`.

Comment: Просто очень странно, что при пробе всех 3 ссылок, мне куки в консоль не выводит, хотя я прописывал это. Я туда добавил для вывода 1 символ, и так же не выводит, получается, что куки нету в ответах? Хотя в headers они есть 
¯\_('-`)_/¯

Comment: Вы ведь уже задавали вопрос, где было обсуждение в чате, в котором выяснилось, что был неверно задан хост для получения кук. Если хотите, можете поискать в интернете код, который будет брать прям все куки, со всеми хостами, учтите, что `www.site`,  `.site` и `site` - это 3 разных хоста в понимании контейнера кук.

Comment: Вас понял, спасибо. Но тот вопрос понятно было, что отличие в `ru` и `com`, а тут который для меня был неизвестен

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я делаю запрос как вы и сказали, он проходит нормально, куки не выдает, `host` я поставил точно такой же как и в postman стоит, как и в fiddler, как везде крч, куки мне не прилетают, менял название `host` на `domain` все то же самое. Делал без превого запроса, сразу на ту ссылку с json, опять та же проблема 404, куки не прилетают, хост `www.icstrvl.ru`

Comment: Сейчас получилось повторить, но это костылями, я обрезал `set-cookie` чтобы получить нужное значение, можете ли мне показать какой хост, т.к я непонимаю. Хост который в httpclient я вставил в postman все заработало, ему куки пришли, мне же не приходят

Comment: [Такой код](https://pastebin.com/EkCMp146) у меня успешно отработал, общий контейнер кук, достаточно отправить раз запрос и после отправлять уже нужный, а ну и ту статичную куку не стоит забыть добавить. Но тут увы, пробовал вам [онлайн](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WAEbQg) пример сделать, так он тоже выдает 404, либо значение статичной куки для его страны другое, либо он чистит значения. По поводу кстати статики: Задается она в `https://www.icstrvl.ru/images/jquery-1.8.2.js`, прям в самом начале функция для этого, а вызов происходит в HTML страницы поиска (`if(window.iep) iep('afx2232_3');`).

Comment: Спасибо, теперь без костылей сделаю)